# report by or from?

Tags: sentence-construction

I am translating a meeting agenda which includes 1)Overview, 2)Goals, etc.
I want to translate a content that suggests each project group to report their progress, issues, improvements or anything related to their projects. In this case, is it okay to name the content like the below?

> 3. Report by each project group
>
>    - Group A
>    - Group B
>    - Group C

Or is it report(s) from? I'm not sure if the word report is appropriate here too.

Comment: Are you asking about how to organize the content? How would it be organized in your language?

Comment: I'm not asking how to organize the content. I'm asking how to name an item in my meeting agenda. Maybe I shouldn't use the word content?

Comment: So you're looking for proofreading of your agenda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, when someone describes their, or the organisation's, recent activities to a formal meeting it is called a report. The agenda usually includes *Chairman's Report, Treasurer's Report* etc.

Either *from* or *by* would be acceptable. (The report comes from the group, and is compiled by members of it.)

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it okay to write "Project groups' reports" too?

Comment: @JiroF., for such a heading, one would more likely use *Project Group Reports*. And although *reports* is fine, you could instead use *updates*; in some sense that might be more specific than *reprts*.

Comment: Thank you. I got it!